# Plotting a bimodal distribution with TikZ

Tags: plot

I have tried without success to plot the curve of a bimodal distribution. Is there a generous soul who can come to my rescue.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). That being said, you might consider looking into `pgfplots` to do the job instead of `tikz` directly

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={binom(\k,\n,\p)=\n!/(\k!*(\n-\k)!)*\p^\k*(1-\p)^(\n-\k);}
]
\begin{axis}[
    samples at={0,...,40},
    yticklabel style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
        /pgf/number format/precision=1
    }
]
\addplot [cyan] {binom(x,40,0.2)+binom(x,40,0.5)}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

that gives:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are referring to the cdf or some other visualization of the distribution?

Maybe `\psBinomialC` instead of `\psBinomialF` is what you want? There are many different options explained in https://mirror.foobar.to/CTAN/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-func/doc/pst-func-doc.pdf

With XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX you can compile (for example in OVerleaf):

```
% Requires XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, LaTeX compiler!!!!!
% Is not compatible with the pdfLaTeX compiler !!!!
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pst-func}

\newcommand{\rightEndPlot}{6.8}
\newcommand{\BinomialN}{4}
\newcommand{\Binomialp}{0.5}
\begin{document}    

% See https://mirror.foobar.to/CTAN/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-func/doc/pst-func-doc.pdf
\psset{xunit=0.8cm,yunit=8cm}%
\begin{pspicture*}[showgrid=false](-1.5,-0.1)(\rightEndPlot,1.2)%
\psset{arrowscale=1.3,arrowinset=0.05,arrowlength=1.9,comma}%
\psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,xticksize=0 1.07,yticksize=0 \rightEndPlot,tickcolor=gray!50,
Dy=0.1,dy=0.1,Dx=1,dx=1,Ox=0]{->}(0,0)(-0.9,0)(\rightEndPlot,1.1)
%\uput[-90](15.8,0){$z$}\uput[0](0,1.1){$P_{0,15}^{100}(Z=z)$}
\psBinomialF[linecolor=red,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow,barwidth=0.4,opacity=0.5,LineEndColorL=red,rightEnd=\rightEndPlot]{\BinomialN}{\Binomialp}
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

[image]